# Can I run all tests from a search result in IntelliJ 12?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've just changed a file. I searched for its usage and discovered some tests that use the file. I can even group them by test / prod resources in the search result. Now I want to execute only those tests - how could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, IntelliJ can already do what I wanted. It was a bug in the search result view which is fixed in the next build. From then on, Ctrl-Shift-F10 will work as for all other views.

Thanks to CrazyCoder for opening the issue at Jetbrains which led to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's not possible yet. I've [created a new feature request for this](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97600), please vote, star or comment the request to receive automatic notifications.